# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor o el texto que aparece en un spinner personalizado?

Tags: java, android, spinner

Tengo un problema con un `spinner`, quiero obtener el valor seleccionado pero me regresa esto:

> esto aparece en el Log: --> package.Tools.CalculdaroaUnidadesTools.Categorias@a42f075 <-- esto viene siendo el valor obtenido del spinner

Cuando quiero recibir "pulgadas" (por ejemplo).

Utilizo esta clase..

```
public class adapter_spinner_categorias extends ArrayAdapter<Categorias> {
private Context context;

List<Categorias> datos = null;

public adapter_spinner_categorias(Context context, List<Categorias> datos)
{
    //se debe indicar el layout para el item que seleccionado (el que se muestra sobre el botón del botón)
    super(context, R.layout.lista_categoria_spinner, datos);
    this.context = context;
    this.datos = datos;
}

//este método establece el elemento seleccionado sobre el botón del spinner
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.lista_categoria_spinner,null);
    }
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texto)).setText(datos.get(position).getName());

    return convertView;
}

//gestiona la lista usando el View Holder Pattern. Equivale a la típica implementación del getView
//de un Adapter de un ListView ordinario
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_spinner, parent, false);
    }

    if (row.getTag() == null)
    {
        adapter_spinner_categorias.UnidadesHolder UnidadesHolder = new adapter_spinner_categorias.UnidadesHolder();
        UnidadesHolder.setTextView((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.texto));
        row.setTag(UnidadesHolder);
    }

    //rellenamos el layout con los datos de la fila que se está procesando
    Categorias categorias = datos.get(position);
    ((adapter_spinner_categorias.UnidadesHolder) row.getTag()).getTextView().setText(categorias.getName());

    return row;
}

/**
 * Holder para el Adapter del Spinner
 * @author danielme.com
 *
 */

private static class UnidadesHolder
{


    private TextView textView;

    public TextView getTextView()
    {
        return textView;
    }

    public void setTextView(TextView textView)
    {
        this.textView = textView;
    }

}
```

Y esta otra clase

```
public class Categorias {
private String name;

public Categorias(String nombre)
{
    super();
    this.name = nombre;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

Aquí donde trato de obtener el valor del `spinner`

```
 cantidad.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            double cant = 0;
            String tipo1 = "",tipo2 = "";
            try{
                tipo1 = spinnerCantidad.getSelectedItem().toString();
                tipo2 = spinnerResultado.getSelectedItem().toString();
                cant = Double.valueOf(cantidad.getText().toString());
            }
            catch(Exception msg)
            {}
            Asignar_formulas.AsignacionFormulasPeso(resultado, tipo1, tipo2, cant);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es, cuando se active el `textChange` de un `EditText`, obtener el ítem del spinner y pasar el valor por parámetro a una función para hacer las conversiones, cuando hacía esto con un simple `arrayList` si me funcionaba, pero cuando personalicé el spinner con el adaptador ya no me funciono.

Espero que con esta info puedan ayudarme.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Como lo estas intentando obtener? como imprimes: package.Tools.CalculdaroaUnidadesTools.Categorias@a42f075

Comment: en el TextChange {
String tipo1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
}

Comment: En el código que agregas no se ve nada acerca de "textChange",  te refieres a un listener? porque no lo agregas-.

Comment: si, es un evento, ya agregue el código en la pregunta

Comment: gracias, veo tienes 2 spinner, imagino usan el mismo adapter. agrego respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtén la referencia del `TextView` que carga tu Custom Adapter:

```
 String spinnerText = ((TextView)spinner.findViewById(R.id.texto)).getText().toString();
```

en tu código:

```
// tipo1 = spinnerCantidad.getSelectedItem().toString();
tipo1 = ((TextView)spinner.findViewById(R.id.texto)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho y fue la solución

Comment: Un placer, cuando preguntes trata de aportar la mayor información necesaria, de esta forma muchas personas aquí te ayudarían, saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ